# What tool do I need for this bolt that holds the crank arm on this stationary bike?

Tags: crankset, bolt

I'm amateur and got this stationary bike. The crank arm, I think that's what it's called, fell off. I can put the bolt back (the one inside the red circle) and turn manually but can't tighten it. There was a cap on top of it. What tool do it need here?

It's completely round and not hex shape
[image]

Comment: Make and model stationary bike?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're showing in this picture.  Is the black arm going to lower-right your crank?   That looks like one half of those fancy 2-part washer pairs called a Nord Lock, or a "wedge washer".  Are you sure there isn't another part missing ?

Comment: If you take the nut back off and turn it around, do you have any hex shape? just a hunch. More important might be why it fell of and if that means any damage to the crank or spindle

Comment: It's a $100 one from a Chinese company I got on Amazon. abdnChap is correct about the wrong way of the nut

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That nut was put in the wrong way around.

This is what the nut looks like:

[image]

The hex end is what you should tighten with a approriate socket.

This is what it should look like when installed correctly:

[image]

If it ever get's super tight as it is now, to get it off, the easiest way is probably to cut it with a tremmel and chisel it out.

Good luck!

Comment: If you tightened it manually you probably remove it manually as well. If not manually you could try with tongue-and-groove-pliers (carefully!)

Comment: Thank you, you are right on. This really gave me a Homer Simpson d'oh moment. The mystery is solved. It's tighten now. Will try working out on it again tonight